# One of my projects does not compile unless I am using Debug mode

Tags: .net, visual-studio, configuration, assemblies

I am having difficulties compiling the test project in my .NET solution solution when using any configuration other than "Debug". I am using a third party assembly (Ninject), the assembly is referenced as usual in my project settings.

It works fine in Debug mode, but when switching to relase I get this error:

Error   13  The type or namespace name 'Core' does not exist in the namespace 'Ninject' (are you missing an assembly reference?)    H:\Sites\Zeiterfassung\Zeiterfassung.Tests\TestBase.cs  10  15  Zeiterfassung.Tests

When I switch back to Debug, everything is working fine again.

Here's what surprised me most: I've tried creating a new solution configuration via Visual Studio 2008's Configuration Manager and copied all settings from the Debug solution. Even the resulting configuration has exactly the same problem.

Comment: Did you reference the debug or the release DLL of this lib?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am guessing that you have added a reference to an Assembly that is located in the bin\Debug folder.  Double check where your references are pointing to.

Comment: Your assumption is correct, I wasn't even aware that this could be a problem. Simply moving the assembly to another directory and referencing it from there fixed it. Thanks! :-)